# inserting the data through the loop

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like below:

```
business
id  name  address
-----------------
1
2
.
.
.
100
```

This table contains 100 records...

Now i am inserting the business table records to business_extra table using loop
target table like below:

```
business_extra 

id  name   address
-------------------





    create or replace function() returns text as
    $$
    begin
    for i in(select * from business)
    loop
    insert into business_extra values(i.id,i.name,i.address);
    end loop;
    end;
    $language plpgsql
```

here exactly what i want means

In this loop i took  first row and then it will insert the row into business_extra 
table...up to 100th row complete then only it will insert.

but i dont want that if i fetch 1st record then it will insert data in business_extra

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you are attempting to do here.

Answer (score 1):

> using loop

It is totally unnecessary to use a PL/PgSQL function and a loop here. It's also very inefficient. Do it with plain SQL:

```
INSERT INTO business_data (id, name, address)
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.address
FROM business i
ORDER BY i.id
LIMIT 100;
```

as an example. I'm guessing about what you mean by "until 100", and guessing that you want the first 100 businesses as sorted by `id`.

Your original function is probably wrong, since it can take *any* 100 businesses in some random order. `SELECT` results have no order unless you specifically specify one.

> but i dont want that if i fetch 1st record then it will insert data in business_extra

I have no idea what you are trying to say with this part.